# Invalid operands to binary expression

Tags: c++, data-structures, vector

I am receiving the following error:

> Invalid operands to binary expression ("`basic_ostream<char,std::_1::char_traits<char>>`' and '`value_type`' (aka '`qElem`'))
>   which occurs at:
>
> ```
> cout << "Your first task is to: " << tasks.front() << endl;
> ```

The code suggest I place a `&` at `&tasks.front()` but I do not want to receive a value of `0xfdlkajd`, I want the first value stored within my vector.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

My code:

```
#ifndef Queue_queue_h
#define Queue_queue_h

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;


struct qElem { //qElem Struct

    string s;
    string p;
    qElem(string task, string priority) : s(task), p(priority) {}

};


//Establishing my Template and PriQueue Class
template <class T> //Template
class PriQueue
{
public:

    vector<qElem> tasks;

    //PriQueue();
    void enqueue(T str, int pri); //Adds to queue
    void dequeue(); //Deletes from queue
    void peek(); //Prints the first value in queue
    void size(); //Prints how many in queue
    void sort(vector<qElem*> &tasks); //Sort according to priority

private:

    int count = 0;

};

template <class T1>
void PriQueue<T1>::enqueue(T1 str, int pri) //Adding an element to the queue
{

    tasks.push_back(qElem(str, pri));

    sort(tasks); //NEW ERROR IS HERE

    count++;

}

template <class T1>
void PriQueue<T1>::dequeue() //Removing an element from the front of the queue
{
    //tasks.erase(tasks.begin());
    tasks.erase(tasks.begin());

    if (tasks.empty()) {
        cout << "You have no tasks!" << endl;
}

    else {


    }

    count--;

}

template <class T1>
void PriQueue<T1>::peek() //Returning a value at front of the queue (NOT removing it)
{
    if (tasks.empty()) {
        cout << "You have no tasks!" << endl;
}

else {
        cout << "Your first task is to: " << tasks.front().s << endl;

}

//Testing Purposes only
/*
 cout << "Your tasks are:";
 for (typename vector<T1>::iterator i = tasks.begin() ; i != tasks.end(); ++i)
 cout << " " << *i << ",";
 cout << endl;
 */

}

template <class T1>
void PriQueue<T1>::size() //Returning the number of items in the queue.
{
    cout << "You have " << count << " tasks in queue." << endl;

}

template <class T>
void PriQueue<T>::sort(vector<qElem*> &tasks) {
bool sortUp = true;
for(int i = 0; i < tasks.size();i++)
    for(int j = i+1; j < tasks.size(); j++)
    {
        if(sortUp)
        {
            if(tasks[i] > tasks[j])
                swap(tasks[i],tasks[j]);
        }
        else if(tasks[i] < tasks[j]) //else sortDown
            swap(tasks[i],tasks[j]);
    }
}


#endif
```

Comment: qElem must implement the operator<<

Comment: @agrum I have another error question which is somewhat relative, I just think it would be a waste creating an entire new question for it.  I have updated my code above and added a sort function.  Now I am trying to use that sort function in my enqueue function but i get the following error:  Non-const lvalue reference to type 'vector<qElem *>' cannot bind to a value of unrelated type 'value_type' (aka 'qElem')   What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler has no idea how to print out a `qElem`. If you want to print out the task only, use `cout << "..." << tasks.front().s << endl;`. The compiler knows how to print a `std::string`. (You can also implement your own `operator <<` overload for `qElem`, but that's probably overkill in this case.)

Note that your code has lots of problems. Why are you using a template `PriQueue` when your `qElem` only stores `std::string`s? Why are you using class members (`ss` and `pp`) to store temporary values in your constructor? Is your priority an `int` (constructor) or a `std::string` (`qElem`) or a `T`?

Comment: "Why are you using a template PriQueue when your qElem only stores std::strings?"  Well originally I was passing an int and a string in my struct like this: string s;
    int p;
    qElem(string task, int priority) : s(task), p(priority) {} but this gives me an error at: tasks.push_back(qElem(ss, pp)); declaring that "No matching constructor for initialization of 'qElem'"  P.s. sorry for the late replay

Comment: Nevermind I figured it out,  I may just be tired.  Thank You for all your help.

Comment: I have another error question which is somewhat relative, I just think it would be a waste creating an entire new question for it. I have updated my code above and added a sort function. Now I am trying to use that sort function in my enqueue function but i get the following error: Non-const lvalue reference to type 'vector<qElem *>' cannot bind to a value of unrelated type 'value_type' (aka 'qElem') What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @user260739 You tried to pass `tasks`, a `vector<qElem>`, to a function that is defined to takes a reference to a `vector<qElem*>`. This is the sort of extremely basic mistakes that you should be able to detect and correct without assistance if you want to write anything more than the extremely basic C++ program. This is absolutely not how you are supposed to implement priority queues, btw. An O(N^2) sort after each insertion?

Answer (score 1):

qElem must implement the operator<<

```
struct qElem { //qElem Struct

    string s;
    string p;
    qElem(string task, string priority) : s(task), p(priority) {}

    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const qElem & obj)
    {
      os << s << "/" << p;
      return os;
    }
};
```