# Code compiles properly with 'make', but shows error on XCode

Tags: xcode

My code compiles well with 'make.' However, when I attempt to do the same with Xcode, the code shows the following error:

"Invalid operands to binary expression ('const value_type' (aka 'const Vertex') and 'const value_type' (aka 'const Vertex'))"

I would be grateful if someone please point me towards a solution. I am currently using OSX 10.10.4 and Xcode 6.3.2. The corresponding screenshot is kept here:

[image: Screen-shot of the error]

Comment: Welcome to SO, To reduce redundant questions you should always search this site before posting a question. A quick search of the error message will show you many answers with similar problems. I have given a basic approach to solving the problem but you can review other answers as there may be an answer specific to your use-case. Also if you find an exact matching answer feel free to delete this question. If the Q&A is unique then please accept my answer if it is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The error message seems clear. You can't use == to compare these two objects. Research and discover another way to compare those object or amend the == operator so that it accepts the types you'd like to compare.

A search of similar error messages on SO yields a number of good answers including:

[Invalid operands to binary expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23839780/invalid-operands-to-binary-expression)

Comment: Thank you very much. However, I am using some one else's code and I know C++ just enough to make some changes. The error posted on the screenshot is actually in 'list', which is an inbuilt header file. The error in the main code is: http://www.civil.iitb.ac.in/~minamdar/XCodeError.png. The frustrating thing is that, when I use 'make' at the command line, the program compiles well. However, with Xcode, the program shows this error. Could you please provide any additional pointers? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just tried a simple solution. Deleted Xcode 6.3.2 and installed back Xcode 6.1.1. Everything now works fine. I have no idea though what has really happened here.

Comment: That sounds more like problem avoidance than a real solution.

Comment: I think, I am aware of this fact! Nonetheless, if anyone knows the actual solution, I would be grateful that they kindly help.  The code compiled in 6.1.1, but not in 6.3.2 seem to indicate some  change that is not compatible with the code--that's the only thing I understand. I am no expert, and I would still be grateful if some expert on this forum can point me towards the real solution.